# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'number | Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>' has no compatible call signatures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm setting up state to be passed through context in React (with hooks). When using the dispatched state updater function, I get this error:

`Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'number | Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>' has no compatible call signatures`

I'm pretty new to TypeScript, and I think that I might be just missing a type somewhere, but I'm stuck

Initially I was trying to pass the `defaultValue` (which in my case is a `number`) and then tried passing the state and updater into the Provider's value. BUT... the type is inferred from that context's `defaultValue` - which is required (for some reason). So that doesn't work...

I'm passing the `value` to both `React.createContext()` and `PatsContext.Provider`. Again, because a defaultValue is required in `React.createContext()`:

```js
import * as React from 'react';

const [pats, givePats] = React.useState(0);
const value = React.useMemo(() => [pats, givePats], [pats]);
const PatsContext = React.createContext(value);

function PatsProvider() {
  return <PatsContext.Provider value={value} />;
}

function GoodBoi() {
  const [, givePats] = React.useContext(PatsContext);

  return (
    <button onClick={() => givePats(prevPats => prevPats + 1)} type='button'>
      Good Boi!
    </button>
  );
}

function PatsDisplay() {
  const [pats] = React.useContext(PatsContext);
  return <div>The good boi has received {pats} pats.</div>;
}

function GoodBoiExample() {
  return (
    <PatsProvider>
      <PatsDisplay />
      <GoodBoi />
    </PatsProvider>
  );
}

export default GoodBoiExample;
```

Trying to use `givePats()` yields the TypeScript error as described above.

Also, using `<PatsProvider />` in the `<GoodBoiExample />` component yields this error as well:

`Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.`

Not sure what that means. But I like to think that once I get passed the first error this will fall in line? ¯_(ツ)_/¯ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Needed explicitly defined type:

```js
type UpdateState = React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>;

const [pats, givePats] = React.useState<number>(0);
const value = React.useMemo<[number, UpdateState]>(() => [pats, givePats], [pats]);
const PatsContext = React.createContext(value);

function PatsProvider({ children }) {
  return <PatsContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</PatsContext.Provider>;
}
```

Passing `children` inside of the context provider infers the type `any` to children - as I think it should be? This solves the second error.

Alternatively I could've passed the `initialValue` as an object with my `state` and `updater`. Type inference would've been more explicitly `number` for the state and `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>` for the updater instead of being infered as `(number | Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>)`. However, the second error's solution remains the same.